An infinite number of figures
In order...


231, 1, 385, 627, 30, 627, 30, 176,135

The answer is a single word. Good luck!

Added the knowledge-tag but it's only, or at least mostly, required once you have an idea what's going on.


 Partition


 The diagram depicts the sequence of partitioning of boxes (integers). This led me to look at the partition function a(n)OEIS. The listed values correspond to a(n) of various n values. These n-values are between 1 and 20 and setting them to their alphabet index gives the answer.


Correct, well done!
